# Less css with theme

Tags: html, css, less

I used LESS CSS for my CSS document. The website have different themes. In the head i put two CSS links. Like this:

```
<!-- Theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="static/css/themes/brabantzorg.less">

<!-- Global -->
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="static/css/style.less">
```

I the theme less file. I put the different colors for the thema in the theme less file. I have a lot of different theme files.

In the global css file. I put the global css with less.

But now i have a problem. The less variables that i put in the theme less file. Are not working in style.less. How can i fix this. A example can you see here: [Here](http://mikevierwind.nl/demo)

The problem that less give:

**variable @color-paragraphs is undefined
http://localhost/Regioportals/html/static/css/style.less on line 292, column 10:**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LESS files don't share state.

The variable `@color-paragraphs`, which you declare inside `brabantzorg.less` is no longer available when `style.less` is being processed.

What you need to do instead is `@import brabantzorg` inside `style.less`.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is interpreted top to bottom
so you must put the  theme css below global one